# Can I run a flexible cord between a ceiling-mounted LED light and wall outlet?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, bedroom, fire-hazard

I am planning to add a ceiling-mounted light in one of the corners of a bedroom. Unfortunately, the only power source I could find is from a wall outlet. I do not want to get into the trouble of installing a new raceway/conduit for this light since it is barely 10 Watts anyways.

I want to power this LED through a flexible cord run **outside** the ceilings and walls with cable clips to the outlet. I also intend this flexible cord to be terminated with a plug so I could remove power from the light and the whole cord as necessary.

Are there any probable code violation or any safety concerns here?

Comment: i've seen lamps sold like this, often with decorative brass chain and terminated with a plug. They are just lamps code-wise, if you want to clip it to the ceiling and walls to keep the cords out of the way, go for it.

Answer (score 3):

This should be OK, as long as all cords are *not* in walls or ceiling - i.e., you can't put in a true ceiling fixture and poke the cord up into the ceiling next to the fixture.

However, a better choice may be to use low-voltage LED lighting. You have a small power pack that plugs in to the wall and you connect one or more low-power cables between the power pack and the light fixtures.

There was a question here recently about extensions for IKEA low-voltage lighting. The included cords were, IIRC, 11' long, and extensions were available (the question was about making your own extensions, which was also an option). Low-voltage (typically < 50V) remove a lot of the safety concerns, and regulations, that regular 120V and 240V circuits have.

Comment: Just curious.. Are you saying the OP can clip flexible, lamp cord, to a ceiling and wall, exposed and not protected, and run it to an outlet?

Comment: @JACK If you have a factory assembled lamp with a cord, I see no reason you couldn't clip the cord to the wall mount the lamp on the wall or ceiling and plug it in to a receptacle.

Comment: Maybe if it as a factory assembled unit but this sounds like a piecemeal project. So you could install a ceiling fan the same way: a cord through the canopy, clipped to the ceiling and down the wall and plugged into an outlet.  You can't even have exposed NB cable into a panel without protection.  Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: The difference is between permanently installed wiring and stuff you plug in. A ceiling fan, pretty much by definition, *must* be permanently installed. I do agree that OP's initial question implies a piecemeal project, and that is where it gets a bit messy. I really didn't address the OP's idea directly so much as provide an alternative that avoids the "how do you protect 120V wiring" problem by simply not having 120V wiring.

Comment: @JACK I thought the point of having flexible wires exposed is to have them easily visible in case of damage?

Comment: There are two different issues. "flexible" isn't exactly the point. Any *permanently* installed wiring needs to be protected against (a) user damage - so if *outside* walls then needs to be protected up to (I think) 8', and (b) hidden damage such as from putting nails/screws into a wall - so inside walls needs to be either protected with nail plates or conduit or far enough away to be out of range of typical problems *or* not permanently attached - i.e., loose NM dropped into a wall cavity down to a receptacle doesn't need protection because if someone puts a nail through the drywall if it

Comment: happens to be right where the cable is, the cable is loose and will move out of the way and is unlikely to be damaged. For plug-in stuff, the issues are a little different. They generally are *not* installed inside walls/ceilings so that takes away the hidden damage issue. My understanding (but if someone has code citations, let me know) is that for plug-in stuff, unless required by the manufacturer's instructions, it does not need protection from damage. That being said, cord covers of various types are a good idea for semi-permanent installation of plug-in stuff. "Flexible" specifically

Comment: enters into the *type* of cable. *Cordage* is the flexible cords we are used to on plug-in appliances, extension cords, etc. Because it is very flexible (unlike NM cable, for example), it can handle being pushed around on a frequent basis and that actually protects against a lot of otherwise incidental damage - e.g., move a piece of furniture against cordage (as long is it isn't trapped/pinched underneath) and the cord will move just fine - do the same with NM cable and it won't bend nearly as easily and repeated actions are likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the wattage is. What matters is the voltage and it's 120 volts. You cannot just staple or clip cord to a ceiling and/or walls. It has to be protected. You will need a cable guard run along the ceiling and down the wall to the outlet. There are numerous types at your home store similar to the one pictured below. they usually come with an adhesive backing and corner fitting.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need all this for "portable lamp"s (the kind you plug in). One might want it, but they don't need it.

Comment: A problem with this approach is I couldn't think of a way of reducing the tension on the cord especially if the *Wiremold* used is too wide. With cable clips, it's a little simpler since you could just knot some parts of the cord near one of the clips so the tension isn't only on the terminations.

Comment: @dandavis  You're right about the old "swag chain" lights. They were UL listed and I put up a few in my younger years but the OP is talking about a piecemeal  installation: a light mounted on the ceiling, some cord poked into it  (no junction box)  and  plug put on the other end. This was my concern. A swag would be fine.